# how handle muti-exception in mockito doThrow

Tags: mockito

this is  a example :

```
try{
}catch(A){
}catch(B){
}
```

how handle this in the mock? I just want to throw one exception ,how to handle another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method invocation can not throw two different exceptions. It can throw one, or the other, but not both at once.

So create a mock and tell it to throw A to test your `catch(A)` block. Then create another test where you tell the mock to throw B to test your `catch(B)` block